# Python CSV file import and object manipulation

Tags: python, beginner, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file and save data in objects for later manipulation in Python. I am very new to coding so please do let me know my fundamental errors.

```
import csv
import os
import time
import numpy
import itertools

def __init__(p):        
    p.playerFile = csv.reader(open("dk.csv", "rb"))
    p.playerList = []
    p.playerName = ''
    p.playerPosition = ''
    p.PlayerGameInfo = ''
    p.playerPrice = 0

def loadCSV(p):
    for row in p.playerFile:
        playerObject = Player()
        playerObject.setPlayerName(row[1])     # Store player name
        playerObject.setPlayerPosition(row[0]) # Store player position
        playerObject.setPlayerGameInfo(row[3]) # Store player team
        playerObject.setPlayerPrice(row[2])    # Store player price

def getPlayerName(p):
    return p.PlayerName

def getPosition(p):
    return p.playerPosition

def getGameInfo(p):
    return p.PlayerGameInfo

def getPrice(p):
    return p.PlayerPrice

def setPlayerName(p, player):
    p.playerName = name

def setPlayerPosition(p, playerPosition):
    p.playerPosition = position

def setPlayerGameInfo(p, PlayerGameInfo):
    p.PlayerGameInfo = team

def setPlayerPrice(p, playerPrice):
    p.playerPrice = price

with open('~/dk.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print (row)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you use this code elsewhere in your program?

Answer (score 4):

## Style

Use *snake_case* instead of *mixedCase* when in Python. In general, follow [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

## Implementation

It seems you have a `Player` class defined somewhere. Then, you use global functions as getters and setters. This has two problems:

1. In [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), getters and setters should be [instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods), e.g. of the `Player` class.
2. Python is not Java. Pythonic code [wouldn't normally use getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627022/2537690).

## Design

Judging by `loadCSV`, each row of a CSV file will become a `Player` object. However, all `Player`s do is store attributes for getting and setting. Save the hassle by using a dictionary for a player. Then just store all your dictionaries in a list.

To understand this code, you will need to understand [comprehensions](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

```
import csv

# Map row to dictionary (dictionary comprehension)
def player(column_names, row):
    return {column_names[column]: data for column, data in enumerate(row) if column < len(column_names)}

# Map CSV file to list of dictionaries (list comprehension)
players = [player(['name', 'position', 'game_info', 'price'], row) for row in csv.reader(open('dk.csv', 'r'))]
```

Running this code on the following CSV file

```
Louis Fernando,Batter,Washington,400
Hose Ricardo,Pitcher,San Fernando,900
```

sets `players` to a list of dictionaries as below.

```
[{'game_info': 'Washington',
  'name': 'Louis Fernando',
  'position': 'Batter',
  'price': '400'},
 {'game_info': 'San Fernando',
  'name': 'Hose Ricardo',
  'position': 'Pitcher',
  'price': '900'}]
```

Then player objects can be accessed like so

```
print(players[0]['game_info']) # prints Washington
players[1]['name'] = "James Jones"
```

### Notes

#### Types

This doesn't take care of types, e.g. the price field maps to a string, not a number. I'm not exactly sure what you're doing overall, so I'll leave that to you.

#### CSV Format

Columns in your CSV file beyond those named in `column_names` will be ignored.

e.g. passing four names (`['name', 'position', 'game_info', 'price']`) to `player` when a row in the CSV file contains five columns.

```
Louis Fernando,Batter,Washington,400,lol
Hose Ricardo,Pitcher,San Fernando,900
```

will produce the same result as the first example.

Comment: Lambda expressions allow creation of *anonymous* functions. When you assign a name (`player`), a `def` statement is appropriate.

Comment: Luke, when I run the codeit returns an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kenny/v3.py", line 8, in <module>
    players = [player(['name', 'position', 'game_info', 'price'], row) for row in csv.reader(open('/home/kenny/dk.csv', 'r'))]
  File "/home/kenny/v3.py", line 5, in player
    return {column_names[column]: row[column] for column in range(len(row))}
  File "/home/kenny/v3.py", line 5, in <dictcomp>
    return {column_names[column]: row[column] for column in range(len(row))}
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @KennyG Note I'm using Python 3. I have edited `player` to handle this by adding `if index < len(column_names)` to the comprehension. The result of this change is explained in `Notes`.